# How to check if a string is part of any string in a list of strings with Groovy?

Tags: string, list, groovy

**Given**

```
String myString = "blah"
List list = ["a", "b", "cblah", "dblah"]
```

**Task**

Check if "blah" is contained in any element of `list`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Solution**

```
println list.any { it.contains(myString) }
println list.find { it.contains(myString) }
list.findAll { it.contains(myString) }.each { print it + " " }
```

**Console output**

```
true
cblah
cblah dblah
```

**Explanation**

[`any`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#any%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) returns true or false.

[`find`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#find%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) returns the first element that contains "blah".

[`findAll`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#findAll%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) returns all elements that contain "blah".